# Как передать интерфейс? MVP

Tags: java, android, mvc, mvp

Решил разобраться как работать с использованием шаблона MVP и вот нашел [такую статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/131446/) на хабре.

Суть в том, что `presnter`-у, как рычаги управления передается 2 интерфейса один на представление(View) и другой на модуль(БД).

При создании `view` создается обьект `presnter`-а и передается ему вот эти 2 ссылки на интерфейсы `View` и `Module`...

В статье которую я указал по ссылке выше приводится вот такой код класса `presnter`

```
public class presenter
{
IView view;
IDataBase dataBase;
int Id;
public presenter(IView view, IDataBase dataBase)
{
    this.view = view;
    this.dataBase = dataDase;
    id = view.getId();
    string name = dataBase.loadFromDB(id);
    view.setName(name);
}

public onSave()
{
    string name = view.getName();
    dataBase.saveToDB(id, name);
}
}
```

Так вот вопрос вот в чем :

я понимаю, что `View` при создании реализует интерфейс `IView`, создает экземпляр `presenter` и передает ему ссылку на уже реализованный `IView` интерфейс, но где `View` берет ссылку на интерфейс `IDataBase` которую так же нужно передать при создании обьекта `presenter`?

Comment: Мне кажется в статье ошибка. Так как view не должен ничего знать о модели и базе данных. Presenter должен инициализировать объект реализации базы данных `dataBase = new DatabaseImpl();`
Автор данной статьи довольно сомнителен. Он даже именует классы с маленькой буквы, что не запрещается, но считается плохим тоном

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDataBase - mock объект, который нужен для тестирования и только. Он подразумевает работу с БД. В приложение же Вы можете создавать объект для работы с БД в конструкторе presenter. А в данном примере получается что view слой создает IDataBase и передает в presenter